# ScrollTo não para exatamente no lugar (#idSection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Estou usando o efeito scrollTo tweenmax, porem estou com um problema, o site eh composto por algumas sections cada uma tem um id que uso de ancora no scrollTo.

Quando clico no menu o site desliza (desce) até a section que selecionei porem ele ultrapassa o inicio da section ficando em cima do `h2.title` e quando estou abaixo dessa section e clico para que ele deslize (suba) até ela o site não para no mesmo lugar que parou quando desce. (estranho pq a ancora eh a mesma)

O código que uso é esse:

```js
$(function(){
  var wrapper = $("#wrapper"),
  $menu = $("#menu");

  $menu.on("click","li", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $(this).find("a").attr("href"),
        topY = $(href).offset().top;

      TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:topY, x:0}, ease:Cubic.easeIn});

    return false;
  });

});
```

Ja tentei usar `y:topY -70`por exemplo mas não deu certo, ele ate fica -70px para cima porem não resolver meu problema.

Resolveria se ele respeitasse exatamente o inicio da section.

**Atualizado:**

O HTML ta mais ou menos assim:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="section-1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="section-2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="section-3">Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <section id="section-1"> Conteudo 1</section>
   <section id="section-2"> Conteudo 2</section>
    <section id="section-3"> Conteudo 3</section>
</div>
```

**Atualização 2**

O menu quando encosta na parte superior do browser fica fixo no topo, ele tem 70px de altura, então coloquei o `y:topY -70` para descontar, mas tb n ficou legal, porem se eu tiro o menu fixo ai funciona legal.  oO

**Atualização 3 - Menu Fixo**

```js
 // Menu fixo top
 var offset = $('#menu').offset().top;
 var $meuMenu = $('#menu');
 $(document).on('scroll', function () {
     if (offset <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
         $meuMenu.addClass('fixar');
     } else {
         $meuMenu.removeClass('fixar');
     }
 });
```

**Atualização 4**
Segue o link para ver na pratica o erro, obrigado.

[Link do Site](http://www.playlearn.com.br/new/public/)

Comment: Como está o HTML?

Comment: Atualizei @user3453562

Comment: Cara, não conheço essa biblioteca, mas acredito que é válido tentar desta forma:

$(e.target.hash).offset().top para sua posição vertical.

Comment: @AlmerNakano tentei aqui mas n rolou =/